# Why does one thread performs much faster then many?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice

I encountered this in production code, here is a simplified example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1); // slower for > 1
    List<CompletableFuture<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        CompletableFuture<Void> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
        futures.add(future);
        executor.submit(() -> {
            int sum = 0; // prevent compiler to get rid of the loop
            for (int j = 0; j < 1_000; j++) {
                String random = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(100, 10_000);
                sum += random.length();
            }
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " sum: " + sum);
            future.complete(null);
        });
    }

    executor.shutdown();

    // prevent program to exit before branched threads complete
    for (CompletableFuture<Void> future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }

    System.out.println("Completed in: " +
            (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
}
```

TL;DR: I just generate some Strings using `apache-commons RandomStringUtils`. No explicit synchronizations.

My question is, why that code perfoms much slower when I increase the number of threads in `FixedThreadPool`?

Here are the results for 1 and 10 threads (tested on 8-core hyper threaded cpu):

1 thread:

```
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5208706
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 4934655
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5173253
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5016372
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 4949229
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5267758
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5156963
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5112007
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 4986156
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 4916637
Completed in: 1431
```

10 threads:

```
pool-1-thread-6 sum: 4928768
pool-1-thread-10 sum: 4946490
pool-1-thread-5 sum: 4955353
pool-1-thread-8 sum: 5043251
pool-1-thread-3 sum: 5125496
pool-1-thread-4 sum: 5045113
pool-1-thread-2 sum: 5040489
pool-1-thread-1 sum: 5123954
pool-1-thread-9 sum: 5090715
pool-1-thread-7 sum: 5399434
Completed in: 11547
```

So it's like x10 times slower with 10 threads. Two threads performs ~ x1.5 times slower then one.

I'm familiar with Amdahl's law. But I'm not sure, is that the case? It seems to me such kind of work should be easily parallelized.

Comment: It could run faster but you would  need to use multiple threads but you are using a fixed size pool of 1. The only reason for any speed up is the code is warmer the second time you run it (ie. some of it will be pre-compiled)

Comment: You should use a benchmark framework to test your code, if you test performance. Benchmarking is hard and you're doing it totally the wrong way.

Comment: I'm familiar with JIT optimizations and microbenchmarking frameworks like JMH. As I said, it's just simplified example, our production code is 10 times slower with multimple threads, how it can be explained?

Comment: > code is warmer the second time. Code is x10 times slower the second time i ran it, please look at the question

Comment: > you are using a fixed size pool of 1. @PeterLawrey, again, please look at the question. Results for 1 and 10 threads are presented

Comment: Your random character generator is going to be synchronized.

Comment: @silent-box when you run the code for the second thread is it a little faster. Obviously running the program again is no warmer as the JVM re-compiles everything from scratch each time.

Comment: The code is slower with multiple threads because you are using a contended resource and the overhead of using that contended resource mean mean that N thread is N times slower or worse.

Comment: most time-comsumung operation is RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(), and it is not parallelized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect the reason that it doesn't scale well is in Apache's code.

I found that `RandomStringUtils` uses the standard `java.util.Random` which is known to not scale well with multiple threads, because of this kind of code:

```
protected int next(int bits) {
    long oldseed, nextseed;
    AtomicLong seed = this.seed;
    do {
        oldseed = seed.get();
        nextseed = (oldseed * multiplier + addend) & mask;
    } while (!seed.compareAndSet(oldseed, nextseed));
    return (int)(nextseed >>> (48 - bits));
}
```

This uses an `AtomicLong` for the `seed`.  In other words, all the threads use the same `Random` instance which use the same `AtomicLong`.  This will cause contention between the threads (especially since you are generating such long random strings) and they will waste of lot cycles doing needless synchronisation.

When I tested it with a different kind of CPU consuming function (a loop that sums), the scaling with multiple threads worked as expected.

Comment: Well spotted: they use the standard `java.util.Random`, and its documentations mentions this explicitly: "Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance."

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed it is the standard `Random`.  I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you! It makes perfect sence.